# bias and variance calculation for linear regression

Tags: python, python-3.x, linear-regression

If we have 4 parameters of X_train, y_train, X_test, and y_test, how can we calculate the bias and variance of a machine learning algorithm like linear regression?

I have searched a lot but I could not find a single code for this.

Comment: are you referring to mean squared error and variance explained by the regression?

Comment: @KaiAeberli I don't think so. I don't know if bias is mean square error or not.

Comment: i see - could you please define what bias means for you

Comment: Bias refers to the tendency of a measurement process to over- or under-estimate the value of a population parameter. but I want to use bias and variance for showing bias-variance trade-off in my machine learning algorithm which is linear regression

Answer (score 1):

So in terms of a function to approximate your population, high bias means underfit, high variance overfit. To detect which, partition dataset into training, cross validation and test sets.

A low training error but high cross validation error means its overfit. 
A high training error means its underfit.

High Bias: add polynomial features, get more samples. High Variance: increase regularisation (squeeze polynomial parameters small), or gather more data so it trains better

Answer (score 1):

Evaluation of Variance:

Variance = np.var(Prediction) # Where Prediction is a vector variable obtained post the
# predict() function of any Classifier.

SSE = np.mean((np.mean(Prediction) - Y)** 2) # Where Y is your dependent variable.
# SSE : Sum of squared errors.

Bias = SSE - Variance

```
# Load dataset
  from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
  X, y = load_boston(return_X_y=True)

# Split the dataset into train and test 
  X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, 
  test_size=0.33, random_state=1)

# Model definition
  model_lr = LinearRegression()

# Fitting training set into model
  model_lr.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Predicting using Linear Regression Model
  Prediction = model_lr.predict(X_test)

# Evaluating variance
  Variance = np.var(Prediction)  # O/P : 56.55085515632455


# Evaluating SSE
  SSE = np.mean((np.mean(Prediction) - y)** 2)  
  # O/P : 85.03300391390214

# Evaluating Variance
  Bias = SSE - Variance
  # O/P : 28.482148757577583
```

Comment: I like this answer, but it could really use some explanation as well as pros/cons.

Comment: Why you thake the ```np.mean(Prediction)```??.. I think it needs only the ```Predictions``` because mean of those values is a single number which is substracted from the ```Y``` (based on your answer).

Comment: Hello @NikSp, as per the article in the link below, 
SSE is the sum of the squared differences between each actual value(observation) and its group's mean.

https://hlab.stanford.edu/brian/error_sum_of_squares.html

Comment: @MD004, let me know if the above modified answer works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take on it

Bias -  Bias is the average difference between your prediction of the target value and the actual value.

Variance - This defines the spread of data from a central point like mean or median.

Ideally while model building you would want to choose a model which has low bias and low variance.

A high bias model is a model that has underfit i.e - it has not understood your data correctly whereas a high variance model would mean a model which has overfit the training data and is not going to generalize the future predictions well.

So if you have chosen your parameters poorly or the input parameters are too less then you might see a high bias and low variance model whereas if you choose too many parameters your model might overfit.

[image]

For identifying overfit and underfit models you can just observe your train/test score pattern and determine what model you have.

An underfit model is going to show you less accuracy scores on train data as well that means model has not learned well , whereas an overfit model is going to show very good accuracy on train data and would predict poorly on test data.

Don't think there are any such tools for bias,variance in the context your are asking but cross validating your data and checking its accuracy with various models or same model but different parameters might give you a good idea. Here you can find some good [example](https://scipy-lectures.org/packages/scikit-learn/auto_examples/plot_bias_variance.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the values of bias and variance without going into the calculations, then use the mlxtend library. It has a [function](http://rasbt.github.io/mlxtend/user_guide/evaluate/bias_variance_decomp/) that automatically returns the bias and variance of certain machine learning models. For linear regression, the variance increases as the number of features increase, so to see the bias and variance change you will have to add/remove certain features.

Answer (score 0):

In real life, we cannot calculate bias & variance. Recap: Bias measures how much the estimator (can be any machine learning algorithm) is wrong with respect to varying samples, and similarly variance measures how much the estimator fluctuate around the expected value of the estimator. To calculate the bias & variance, we need to generate a number of datasets from some **known** function by adding noise and train a separate model (estimator) using each dataset. Since we don't know neither the above mentioned **known** function nor the added noise, we cannot do it. In practise, we can only calculate the overall error. In order to combat with bias/variance dilemma, we do cross-validation.